# How to identify different patterns of numbers in a column?

Tags: mysql, powerbi, obiee

I am trying to write one single formula to identify all the patterns in a column/field. For example: Below are the five different patterns

```
AG 5643 895468 UWEB
7546 695321 IJJK
PE 45612384
8642567921
16724385
```

Formula for
First pattern: Contains **4 numbers**  **6 numbers** 
'*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] *' This is not working. Can we specify the length? Something like this [0-9]{4} - 4 digit number?
First pattern should pick second one also.

3rd one: first 2 characters are alphabets  8 or 10 digit numbers

4th one: 10 digit number

5th one 8 digit number

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these are the values in the field.

AG 5643 895468 UWEB 

7546 695321 IJJK 

PE 45612384 

8642567921 

16724385

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in MySQL you can use regular expressions with the RLIKE filter operator.

For example, `WHERE text RLIKE '[0-9]{8}'` finds all the rows with any consecutive sequence of eight digits in them anywhere.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44996/1/0)

`WHERE text RLIKE '^[0-9]{8}%'` finds the rows consisting of nothing but an eight-digit sequence.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44996/2/0)

`WHERE text RLIKE '^[0-9A-Z]{2} '` finds the rows starting with two letters or digits and then a space. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44996/3/0)

You get the idea. Regular expressions have a lot of power to them, generally beyond the scope of a SO answer to explain.  Beware, though. This is a common saying: *If you solve a problem with e regular expression, now you have two problems.* You need to be careful with them.